# issue with setw() and ofstream

Tags: c++, ubuntu, virtualbox, iostream

When I use `setw()` with `ofstream`, it's not writing to the file properly. It is skipping many lines of output and in Notepad++ the output file shows lots of NULLs. But when I try it with `"\t"` it works fine.

Can you please explain why?

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("test.txt");

    for(int i=0;i<300;i++){
        myfile <<"\n"<<setw(15)<<0<<setw(15)<<0<<setw(15)<<10000<<setw(15)<<6000;
        //myfile <<"\n\t"<<0<<"\t"<<0<<"\t"<<10000<<"\t"<<6000;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Edit:

I tested a little more and figured out that the problem is specific to the following configuration. I'm using [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) guest on *win7* using *`virtualbox`* and my program was attempting to write on a file on the host OS drive using *`virtualbox`* shared folder mounted on *ubuntu*.

When I tried to run the program inside *ubuntu* it worked fine. Also, I tried doing the same thing on my personal machine which also has win7 host and *ubuntu* guest. I tried I the same program on a mounted drive from *win7* to *ubuntu* and it worked fine.

I'm wondering if it was because of the settings on my work computer. Anyway its not critical now. But more insights are welcome.

Comment: try putting `setfill(' ')` in there as well, it may not default to space. Just a guess.

Comment: Works fine with my MinGW g++. What is your compiler and operating system?

Comment: Works fine on my Mac as a command line tool (compiled using g++), run in the terminal.

Comment: What do you see if you just "cp" the good file created in your Ubuntu VM onto the mounted folder on the host?  In other words, try to sort out if the problem is occurring in the C++ runtime or in the virtual filesystem itself.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to make sure you really use spaces (or other chars) to set the width between data:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char a='î';
    int  b=15;
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("test.txt");

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
           myfile <<'\n'       <<setfill(a)<<setw(b)
                  <<0          <<setfill(a)<<setw(b)
                  <<0          <<setfill(a)<<setw(b)
                  <<10000      <<setfill(a)<<setw(b)
                  <<6000       ;
    }
    myfile <<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

gives

$ g++ a.cpp -std=c++0x -Wall  -o a && ./a && cat test.txt

```
::::::::::::::0::::::::::::::0::::::::::10000:::::::::::6000
::::::::::::::0::::::::::::::0::::::::::10000:::::::::::6000
::::::::::::::0::::::::::::::0::::::::::10000:::::::::::6000
```